# Find position of a word in a list in Python

Tags: python, performance

The aim of this program is to say which position a word is in a list. This  is just a basic version of it. I made to see if I could shorten it more than what it is currently.

```
position, word, word_list = 0, 'hello', 'hello what is your name i am bob this is a sentence a very n ice sentence'
word_list = word_list.split(" ")
print(word_list)
if word in word_list:
    for name in word_list:
        position = position + 1
        if word == name:
            print('your word is in the list at ',position)
else:
    print('Your word is not in the sentence')
```

Comment: Alternately `word_list.index(word)`

Comment: @JoeWallis: `.index()` finds only the first match.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @zondo didn't notice that, mb

Comment: Please don't change the code once you get an answer, as it invalidates the answer. See also [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar solution using `enumerate()`:

```
word, word_list = 'hello', 'hello what is your name i am bob this is a sentence a very n ice sentence'

if word in word_list:
    for position, name in enumerate(word_list):
        if name == word:
            print("Your word is in the list at ", position)
else:
    print('Your word is not in the sentence')
```

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
word, word_list = 'hello', 'hello what is your name i am bob this is a sentence a very n ice sentence'

positions = [x for x, n in enumerate(word_list).split() if n == word]
if positions:
    for position in positions:
        print('your word is in the list at ', position)
else:
    print('Your word is not in the sentence')
```

Also, a generator expression that's a little more efficient:

```
word, word_list = 'hello', 'hello what is your name i am bob this is a sentence a very n ice sentence'

found = False
for position in (x for x, n in enumerate(word_list) if n == word):
    print('your word is in the list at ', position)
    found = True
if not found:
    print('Your word is not in the sentence')
```

Comment: i have made  some slight improvements by  using procedures and some input statements. however when i ran it using the enumerate function it said the first word is  position 0 which is  due too computers count from 0 but how could i make it so it counts from 1?

Comment: @Adam.Harris: Use `print(..., position + 1)` instead of `print(..., position)`  You could also use `enumerate(word_list, 1)` instead of `enumerate(word_list)`